# Kotlin put children class type into parent class type

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to have an `object` that collects the listeners for the childrent class of `Message` class.

```kotlin
typealias Listener <T> = (T) -> Unit

object MessageRegistry {
    private val listeners = mutableMapOf<KClass<out Message>, MutableSet<Listener<Message>>>()

    fun <T : Message> listen(clazz: KClass<T>, listener: Listener<T>) {
        listeners.getOrPut(clazz) { mutableSetOf() }.add(listener)
    }
}
```

I want the clients of this object to register their listeners like the following when `ConnectedMessage` is a subtype of `Message`:

```kotlin
MessageRegistry.listen(ConnectedMessage::class) { connectedMessage: ConnectedMessage ->
  doSomething(connectedMessage)
}
```

However, there seems to be a problem in the `MessageRegistry.listen()` method.
I can't get `listener` added to the `MutableSet<Listener<Message>>>`.

The `listener` has a type `(T) -> Unit` with a generic `T` being `<T: Message>` and
I want to added to the `MutableSet` with the type `(Message) -> Unit`.

I'm getting a type error as follows:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Listener<Message> /* = (Message) → Unit */
Found:
Listener<T> /* = (T) → Unit */
```

As I mentioned that the `T` inherits the `Message` class (`<T : Message>`), I think this is a valid conversion.

---

I've also tried marking `out` to the generic type of the `Listener`:

```kotlin
private val listeners = mutableMapOf<KClass<out Message>, MutableSet<Listener<out Message>>>()
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Conflicting projection in type alias expansion in intermediate type '(T) -> Unit'
```

---

What can I do to have the listeners in a set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Listener is a T consumer, not producer, so it cannot be given a type of `out Message` and still be useful.

Since your function allows subtypes of Message for the Listener, but Listener is a consumer, your Listener cannot satisfy the requirement to be a `Listener<Message>`. For example, if you had a `Listener<SubMessage>` and tried to pass a `Message` to it, it would be unsafe because the `Message` might not be a `SubMessage`.

However, since you are storing these in a Map with the class, you are effectively creating runtime-safety of the types, and you can logically deduce types are safe to cast if they match up.

Therefore, the generics system cannot guarantee safety, but you can if you are careful about where you cast. You can implement it like this:

```
object MessageRegistry {
    private val listeners = mutableMapOf<KClass<out Message>, MutableSet<Listener<*>>>()

    fun <T : Message> listen(clazz: KClass<T>, listener: Listener<T>) {
        listeners.getOrPut(clazz) { mutableSetOf() }.add(listener)
    }

    private fun <T: Message> getListeners(clazz: KClass<T>): MutableSet<Listener<T>> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return listeners[clazz] as MutableSet<Listener<T>>
    }
}
```

I suggest making these inline/reified to make your code simpler at the call sites. In most cases, it will be able to infer the type at the call site so you won't have to explicitly pass it.

```
object MessageRegistry {
    private val listeners = mutableMapOf<KClass<out Message>, MutableSet<Listener<*>>>()

    @PublishedApi
    internal fun <T : Message> listen(clazz: KClass<T>, listener: Listener<T>) {
        listeners.getOrPut(clazz) { mutableSetOf() }.add(listener)
    }
    
    inline fun <reified T : Message> listen(noinline listener: Listener<T>) {
        listen(T::class, listener)
    }

    private fun <T: Message> getListeners(clazz: KClass<T>): MutableSet<Listener<T>> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return listeners[clazz] as MutableSet<Listener<T>>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The suggested code with `inline` and `reified` is amazing. 

However, I think the example with the `Listemer<Message>` and `Listener<SubMessage>` is quite opposite from my case. I think my case is trying to put a `SubMessage` into `Listener<Message>`, isn't it?

Comment: I meant if you put a `Listener<SubMessage>` into your collection (if the compiler let you) and later retrieved it, it would not be a valid `Listener<Message>`. That's what the compiler is trying to prevent. A `Listener<SubMessage>` simply is not a `Listener<Message>` because Listener's type is not covariant.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation! It indeed helped a lot :)